# trying to get three json feeds using fragments

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, fragment

i Am creating an app where one of my activities will be making use of fragments. In each fragment view, I am going to be pulling from a data base using three files, three adapters in each view. The first fragment works as expected. However, when I add my json parser code to the second swipe view, I see it tries to fire as soon as the activity is loaded ( i make the second swipe view toast) and The json parser will not load any data into my second view. Should I attach the JSON to the main activity and switch the adapters and URL's as i switch views or should i try to load the JSON from every fragment (which is what I am doing now). Any insight would be greatly appreciated thank you

```
public class chatfragment extends Fragment {

    ListView l;
    List<chatitem> listItem;
    ChatListAdapter adapter;
    String category = "430";
    chatitem item;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chatfragment, container, false);

        l = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chatlist);
        listItem = new ArrayList<chatitem>();
        adapter = new ChatListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.chatfragment, listItem);
        l.setAdapter(adapter);

        new ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask().execute("myurl");

        return rootView;
    }

    public String readJSONFeed (String URL){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if(statusCode == 200){
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            }else{
                Log.d("readJSONFeed", "Failed to download file");
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private class ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        protected String doInBackground(String...urls){
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray subcat  = new
                JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("results"));
                for(int i = 0; i < subcat.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject p = subcat.getJSONObject(i);

                    item = new chatitem(p.getString("hubusername"),p.getString("picture"),p.getString("timeadjust"),p.getString("comment"));

                    listItem.add(item);

                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), p.getString("subcategory"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("ReadWeatherJSONFeedTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do a lot of things. I'd recommend preparing the data (download from Web etc.) in the activity and then loading it into the fragments.

ViewPager prepares not only the current fragment but also the next fragment in the list. If you have an issue with this behaviour you'll have to use the pageChangeListener and updating the fragments when they are active.

Comment: so you are saying I should download three JSON files in my activity, load them into their appropriate array lists, then just display them when I switch to that view? For some reason I could see some bottle neck... especially because not every user will wind up using all three fragments, I am just wasting system resources on both the client and the server. Is there a way for the fragment adapter to not evaluate the next fragment?

Comment: Users prefer speed for lower data usage. If you want to hold back on data usage you could show a spinner if they aren't on wifi and then start dl when they are on the given page.

Comment: Warpzit I am actually more concerned with memory overflow.. when I swipe through the fragments does android automatically get rid of what is there to save memory or does everyhting stay in memory on the swipe views until release them from memory?

Comment: If you use fragmentstatepageradapter on the viewpager they are destroyed when you swipe further away (more than 1 view). ViewPager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter remembers 1 fragment to each side (initial position is only 0 + 1).

Comment: interesting..  I will try it out. If it works I will let you know so you can put it as an answer so other people can also get the benefit of this since swipe adapters are more or less an advanced topic and also you get points.

Comment: Warzpit, when i use my json feed in the activity it does not work and I am not able to use the data. Is there a way I can fix my fragment views so I don't get a postExecute error and I am able to re down load my json feed?

Comment: @Dnaso How do you update your fragments? If you update them from the activity you'll need to make a new method that updates the UK.

Comment: currently the fragments hold all the data code. they are being brought into memory when my activity tells the tabs adapter that a new tab was pressed and i  use the appropriate class depending on the tab. For some reason the onpostexecute of my json methods are getting called twice which means they are firing at the same time. However the listvew is fine but the next fragment fails. I even used the same JSON file to test. Is it because I am accidently creating two async tasks at the same time or because the onpostexecute is getting fired twice from my listview in the first fragment @Warpzit